# python: use command line argument from file A in file B

Tags: python, import, module

I have a python file (e.g. fileA.py) which can accept command line arguments. next i have a call of a couple of functions going through different .py files (filea -> fileb -> filec -> fileX). In filex i want to use the command line argument (in this case a file) given to fileA.

This is the code i use for the command arg parsing:

```
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-c", dest="configfile",help="Input configuration file")
args = p.parse_args()
configfile = args.configfile
if not (configfile):
    p.print_help()
    sys.exit()
f = open(configfile)
config = yaml.load(f)
```

I could just pass it on through each file until it ends at fileX, i have tried this, but this seems far from elegant. Does anyone have a more appropriate solution?

Comment: Why are you not just importing the other files into your main script and call the functions declared in them? No need to parse arguments then except in the first file.

Comment: I'm working with the code from someone else and i was afraid of breaking the program if I made changes like that. But i guess that would work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use arguments in some functions of fileX.py then parse the argument in that function only, it's not needed to be in mainfile. 
e.g.-

## mainfile.py

```
from filex import f
f()
```

## filex.py

```
import argparse
def f():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("-c", dest="configfile",help="Input configuration file")
    args = p.parse_args()
    configfile = args.configfile
    print configfile
```

Then run it as -

```
mainfile.py -c someconfig_file
#it prints - someconfig_file
```

Comment: I had no idea that was possible, thank you very much